# Ruby method lookup from a dispatch table in a module

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm trying to create a concern for a model, but this is a basic Ruby method lookup problem not a Rails issue per se.

I'd like my concern to provide the ability to format a value, by selecting a formatting method based on some characteristic of the value. In the abstracted example below, I want to invoke the `foo` formatter if the value to be formatted has an `:attribute` with value `:a_characteristic`. In particular, I want a dispatch table in which I can map from characteristics to formatting functions.

Here's my attempt:

```rb
module FormatConcern
  FORMATTERS = {
    a_characteristic: ->(v){foo v}
  }

  def format( v )
    FORMATTERS[v[:attribute]].call( v )
  end

  def foo( v )
    "A value with #{v[:foo]}"
  end
end

class ModelWithConcern
  include FormatConcern
end

test_value = {attribute: :a_characteristic,
              foo: "bar"}
m = ModelWithConcern.new
puts "formatted value: #{m.format( test_value )}"
```

When I execute this code, the lookup of the `foo` method fails:

```
$ ruby concern_test.rb 
concern_test.rb:3:in `block in <module:FormatConcern>': undefined method `foo' for FormatConcern:Module (NoMethodError)
from concern_test.rb:7:in `call'
from concern_test.rb:7:in `format'
from concern_test.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I thought I understood how Ruby looks up method names in a class, but clearly I don't understand it well enough! How can I refer to the `foo` method from the lambda functions in my dispatch table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that blocks are lexically bound. Because the block is defined in the context of the module, the `self` in the block refers to the module. The most straightforward way around it would be to take a callee parameter in the formatter block.

```
module FormatConcern
  FORMATTERS = {
    a_characteristic: ->(obj, v){obj.foo v}
  }

  def format( v )
    FORMATTERS[v[:attribute]].call(self, v)
  end

  def foo( v )
    "A value with #{v[:foo]}"
  end
end
```

The other solution would be to `instance_exec` the block instead of calling it:

```
module FormatConcern
  FORMATTERS = {
    a_characteristic: ->(v){foo v}
  }

  def format( v )
    instance_exec(v, &FORMATTERS[v[:attribute]])
  end

  def foo( v )
    "A value with #{v[:foo]}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make foo a class method with `.self`

```
  def self.foo( v )
    "A value with #{v[:foo]}"
  end
```